# Weight function for binomial or negative binomial GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, proportion, negative-binomial-distribution, weights

I am trying to investigate the influence of Sex on the response variable Prop_new_trees (proportion data, No_new_used/Total_trees), with joey_number (a factor) as a covariate. Because I have proportion data I have been trying to fit a binomial GLM in R.

```
> head(exp)
Possum Sex Prop_new_trees joey_number No_prev_used No_new_used Total_trees
1  Cadence   F     0.08333333           1           11           1          12
2 Chechnya   F     0.41666667           1            7           5          12
3     Coco   F     1.00000000           1            0          13          13
4    Comet   F     0.50000000           1            8           8          16
5  Cupcake   F     0.60000000           1           12          18          30
6  Delilah   F     0.25000000           2            3           1           4
```

If I run a basic binomial GLM

```
bb1 <- glm(Prop_new_trees ~ Sex + joey_number, family = binomial, data = exp
```

I get an error message saying non-integer successes. I did a bit of reading and I think I need to add in the weights for each individual - ie. the number of observations per individual (Total_trees) which has been used to calculate the proportions. If I run this:

```
bb <- glm(No_new_used ~ Sex + joey_number, 
        weights = Total_trees, data = exp)

> summary(bb)

Call:
glm(formula = No_new_used ~ Sex + joey_number, data = exp, weights = Total_trees)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-31.295   -8.189    0.471    5.927   43.631  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   13.200      2.489   5.304 4.05e-05 ***
SexM          -3.767      2.229  -1.690   0.1073    
joey_number   -3.166      1.223  -2.587   0.0181 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 307.1152)

    Null deviance: 9051.9  on 21  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5835.2  on 19  degrees of freedom
AIC: 143.31

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> Anova(bb)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: No_new_used
            LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
Sex           2.8573  1   0.090960 . 
joey_number   6.6946  1   0.009671 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My question is, have I interpreted the weights function correctly?

Secondly, my data is positively skewed (there are several zero values, which are all biologically meaningful). If I try using a negative binomial my results become more significant.

[image]

[image]

```
bb <- glm.nb(No_new_used ~ Sex + joey_number, 
        weights = Total_trees, data = exp)

> summary(bb)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = No_new_used ~ Sex + joey_number, data = exp, 
    weights = Total_trees, init.theta = 2.170196952, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-7.2052  -2.9716  -0.9308   1.5414   5.2810  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.22237    0.12152  26.517  < 2e-16 ***
SexM        -0.60528    0.10636  -5.691 1.26e-08 ***
joey_number -0.84772    0.07177 -11.811  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(2.1702) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 454.88  on 21  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 256.19  on 19  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1295.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  2.170 
          Std. Err.:  0.289 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -1287.950 
> Anova(bb)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: No_new_used
            LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Sex           32.176  1  1.408e-08 ***
joey_number  145.946  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is it valid to use a negative binomial without specifying theta, and is negative binomial the better option for my skewed data? (I tried an arcsine transformation but that didn't really help). I didn't have any luck with a poisson distribution because I have different total number of observations for each individual (hence using a proportion), although I don't doubt that there is a way to factor this in somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `glm(cbind(No_prev_used, No_new_used) ~ Sex + joey_number, family = binomial, data = exp)` instead. You won't need weights if you model as cbind(success, failure).

Comment: If you want to use Poisson or negative binomial best to make the response the _number_ of events and add _log(total)_ as an offset. As you surmise for Poisson this is no advance on the binomial..

Comment: Thanks - the cbind has worked perfectly and spits out a significant p-value for both response variables. I ran a test for dispersion using the P__disp function in msme and it shows the model is overdispersed (dispersion value ~4). I have changed to quasibinomial and now the result is non-significant for Sex (binomial p=0.0019, quasibinomial p=0.12). I'm still a bit concerned that the data is not normally distributed - I'm not sure how strict this is for a binomial GLM. I would be keen to hear anyone's suggestions based on the histogram I've included. Thanks!